# Scraping data from Standing Table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to fetch the team names and href links from standing table in the page below, but its source code does not show team name list or etc. Can you please tell me how to get it?

http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Standings/Default.aspx?sId=57488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the API call below and have the data of the standings

```
import requests

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,el;q=0.8,he;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it;q=0.4,es;q=0.3",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Referer": "http://arsiv.mackolik.com/Standings/Default.aspx?sId=57488"
}
r = requests.get('http://arsiv.mackolik.com/AjaxHandlers/StandingHandler.ashx?op=standing&id=57488', headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.json())
else:
    print(r.status_code)
```

output

```
{'id': 57488, 's': [[119, 'Bayern München', 17, 17, 13, 11, 4, 2, 0, 4, 64, 35, 21, 23, 43, 35, 0, 0, '', ''], [911, 'RB Leipzig', 17, 17, 11, 8, 4, 4, 2, 5, 29, 31, 13, 19, 37, 28, 0, 0, '', ''], [120, 'Borussia Dortmund', 17, 17, 11, 9, 2, 2, 4, 6, 40, 35, 20, 26, 35, 29, 0, 0, '', ''], [124, 'Wolfsburg', 17, 17, 10, 7, 4, 6, 3, 4, 32, 29, 16, 21, 34, 27, 0, 0, '', ''], [141, 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 17, 17, 10, 6, 7, 5, 0, 6, 37, 32, 20, 33, 37, 23, 0, 0, '', ''], [133, 'Bayer Leverkusen', 17, 17, 8, 6, 5, 5, 4, 6, 34, 19, 22, 17, 29, 23, 0, 0, '', ''], [146, 'Union Berlin', 17, 17, 8, 4, 8, 6, 1, 7, 32, 18, 18, 25, 32, 18, 0, 0, '', ''], [126, 'Mönchengladbach', 17, 17, 8, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6, 32, 32, 19, 37, 28, 21, 0, 0, '', ''], [129, 'Stuttgart', 17, 17, 5, 7, 6, 3, 6, 7, 27, 29, 26, 29, 21, 24, 0, 0, '', ''], [137, 'Freiburg', 17, 17, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 9, 33, 19, 23, 29, 27, 18, 0, 0, '', ''], [918, 'Hoffenheim', 17, 17, 8, 3, 3, 7, 6, 7, 32, 20, 24, 30, 27, 16, 0, 0, '', ''], [143, 'Mainz 05', 17, 17, 4, 6, 4, 5, 9, 6, 16, 23, 26, 30, 16, 23, 0, 0, '', ''], [916, 'Augsburg', 17, 17, 6, 4, 4, 2, 7, 11, 21, 15, 25, 29, 22, 14, 0, 0, '', ''], [125, 'Hertha Berlin', 17, 17, 5, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 20, 26, 26, 20, 15, 0, 0, '', ''], [130, 'Arminia Bielefeld', 17, 17, 6, 3, 2, 6, 9, 8, 13, 13, 23, 29, 20, 15, 0, 0, '', ''], [138, 'Köln', 17, 17, 3, 5, 5, 4, 9, 8, 20, 14, 31, 29, 14, 19, 0, 0, '', ''], [121, 'Werder Bremen', 17, 17, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 8, 16, 20, 28, 29, 14, 17, 0, 0, '', ''], [122, 'Schalke 04', 17, 17, 3, 0, 3, 4, 11, 13, 14, 11, 34, 52, 12, 4, 0, 0, '', '']], 'f': [], 'r': [[3445271, '22/05', 'MS', 119, 916, '454136', 5, 2, '4 - 0', 4, 1.08, 6.75, 9, 0, 0, 3.3, 4.25, 1.06, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1.22, 4.25, 3.3, 0], [3445274, '22/05', 'MS', 124, 143, '454141', 2, 3, '0 - 1', 4, 1.67, 3.3, 3.25, 1.15, 1.15, 1.6, 2.5, 1.28, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2.4, 3.5, 1.6, 0], [3445272, '22/05', 'MS', 120, 133, '454143', 3, 1, '1 - 0', 4, 1.42, 4, 3.9, 1.1, 1.1, 1.9, 3.1, 1.15, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1.9, 3.5, 1.9, 0], [3445278, '22/05', 'MS', 121, 126, '454138', 2, 4, '0 - 1', 4, 2.75, 3.1, 1.9, 1.48, 1.15, 1.22, 2.25, 1.35, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1.48, 3.5, 2.85, 0], [3445276, '22/05', 'MS', 146, 911, '454139', 2, 1, '0 - 0', 4, 3.1, 3.2, 1.75, 1.55, 1.15, 1.18, 2.05, 1.45, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1.55, 3.25, 2.65, 0], [3445273, '22/05', 'MS', 918, 125, '454140', 2, 1, '0 - 1', 4, 1.52, 3.5, 3.6, 1.12, 1.12, 1.75, 2.55, 1.25, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2.15, 3.4, 1.75, 0], [3445275, '22/05', 'MS', 141, 137, '454142', 3, 1, '0 - 0', 4, 1.85, 3.4, 2.6, 1.25, 1.15, 1.48, 3, 1.18, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2.65, 3.75, 1.48, 0], [3445279, '22/05', 'MS', 129, 130, '454137', 0, 2, '0 - 0', 4, 2.05, 3.1, 2.5, 1.25, 1.18, 1.4, 2.2, 1.38, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3.2, 3.6, 1.4, 0], [3445277, '22/05', 'MS', 138, 122, '454135', 1, 0, '0 - 0', 4, 1.28, 4.4, 5.25, 1.06, 1.08, 2.2, 2.9, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1.65, 3.4, 2.2, 0]], 'd': [[1, 'Şampiyonlar Ligi', 1, 4, '1E365A'], [3, 'Avrupa Ligi', 5, 2, '2270FF'], [60, 'Konferans Ligi Elemeler', 7, 1, '00CCFF'], [13, 'Play Out', 16, 1, 'FA8181'], [6, 'Alt Lig', 17, 2, 'F03B3B']]}
```